# Connecting postgresql to database on other harddrive

Tags: postgresql, hard-drive

I am using Win 10 64 bit and have just installed postgresql here: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13.  I have an older installation here, with lots of tables: F:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data.  Both drives are on the same computer. Can my new installation connect to my database on drive f:?

Answer (score 1):

Does the data need to remain in two separate instances?  If not, you could export the data from one with pg_dump, and import it into the other.  Then decommission the old one.

If you need to maintain separate instances, you could connect them together with [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).  This is very convenient to query across the two instances, but performance usually suffers, often dramatically.

Comment: after using pg_dump (to get the database and tables from postgres 9.6), how do I import the "result" into the new (instance of postgresql 13)?  Thank you Steve

Comment: Are they already in separate schemas?  Do you want then to be?  If not, are there any name collisions between objects?

Comment: I think I remember having several schemas but no name collisions. Thank you, Steve